# Extracting network interface type and name in GoLang on CentOS machine

Tags: docker, go, centos

I have a CentOS virtual machine and I can run a Go binary on it. The machine runs docker containers, etc and some other Go code as well. I am trying to infer by Go Code what is the list of interfaces that are of type "Ethernet". The challenge is that there is no category that I can find in the object that I am getting from Go library. Basically, docker containers also create veth ports, there can be loopback ports and so on and so forth. But I am only interested to filter in the ports that are ethernet ports(not virtual ethernet ports i.e veth ports must be filtered outs). Neither do I want lo or docker0. The challenge is that I cannot easily use string match based on name and decide because name of ports can be `eth` or `ens` or any such name on linux machine.

I have a sample code and sample output but I am trying to see what is the right way to get eth ports.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func availableInterfaces() {

    interfaces, err := net.Interfaces()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    fmt.Println("Available network interfaces on this machine : ")
    for _, i := range interfaces {
        //fmt.Printf("Name : %v \n", i.Name)
        fmt.Printf("Full object : %+v \n", i)
    }
}

func main() {
    availableInterfaces()
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for, but here is docs for [Interface type](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Interface). It has field `Name` that contains network interface name like  "en0", "lo0", "eth0.100". Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin, When a virtual machine will boot up, it will say come up configured with 2 ethernet adapters. Rest of the interfaces like lo, vethXYZ are created later based on various things that are running. The eth adapters on CentOS come with different names like ens or eth so I cannot blindly rely on Name. I am trying to get the ethernet adapters that machine started with, analogous to saying the machine has 2 actual or 3 actual or 5 actual ethernet ports with RJ45 connectors if that was an actual HW box.